# What's the name of functions that produces a non deterministic solution without losing the exact solution?

Tags: computability-theory, definitions, approximation-algorithms

I know that Turing reductions, function reductions and aproximation algorithms can produce good results and aproaches to the solution of a problem, but sometimes they lost the exact solution. Is there a clasification, notation or name for this sort of functions or functors that produce a reduction of the problem (or a non determistic solution) that can be used as well as an aproaching never losing the exact solution?

Comment: [Las Vegas algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Las_Vegas_algorithm)? It is hard to see in what sense [Turing reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_reduction) loses the exact solution. And what is "function reduction"?

Comment: Yep,I'm not sure if a Turing reduction don't lost the exact solution never. A function reduction as well as an approximation can lost the exact solution.